# How to keep an Object between calls without using sessions in Django?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, credit-card

I'm configuring MangoPay for my web application and it's now time for credit card registration. I'm using the python SDK that MangoPay recommends.
The workflow requires a `CardRegistration` to be created on the backend, which can be used to generate a form in the front end. On this form the user adds the credit card details, which are sent to a 3rd party tokenisation service and returned to the users front end. This token can be sent now to my backend and, added to the `CardRegistration` object, can be saved enabling the card for the user.

My issue is that I don't know how to store `CardRegistration` object between calls in the backend while I wait for the user to generate the token and return it.

Sessions can not be used, as the preregistration object contains sensitive data. To prove if it would have worked and I tried to use `pickle` but it raises a `PicklingError`, so serialization and storage doesn't look like an option either.

What should I look into? Is there some kind of design pattern I can use to store the object quickly for retrieval?

Comment: I don't understand why sessions cannot be used.

Comment: This does not appear to follow: "Sessions can not be used, as the preregistration object contains sensitive data." Why does sensitivity mean you can't use sessions?

Comment: So sessions are how it is done normally? How would you recommend me to do it, considering that the `CardRegistration` object is not serialisable?

Comment: Why can't you store the `id` of the `CardRegistration` in session and use that to load the object once you receive the token?